# How can I use Redis() in a PHP Unit Test?

Tags: php, redis, phpunit, php-extension

I am using phpunit and want to use Redis() with it, but when I do something like:

```
phpunit --verbose UnitTest.php
```

It gives something back like:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Redis' not found in......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops.  didn't have redis PHP extension installed

```
yum install php-redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I would install it as follows:

`pecl install redis`

Just a note: If you have php-redis installed with `php.ini` entry correctly added, you need not have redis client installed on your app server to connect to a remote redis server. (y)